# Simplify an expression

Tags: maple

I'm a maple newbie and I would like to simplify this expression as much as i can:

$$g(q) =  -8 \cdot 2^q + 8 \cdot 2^{\frac{3}{2}q} + 1$$

In such case i would like to write the expression like:

$$g(q) = -2^{q+3} + 2^{\frac{3}{2}q + 3} + 1  \;\;\;\; (1)$$

and then factorize $2^q$ in order to have:

$$g(q) = 2^{q+3}(2^{\frac{q}{2}} - 1) + 1 \;\;\;\; (2)$$

Is it possible to have at least the expression (1)? What about the (2)? assume the original one is given, $q$ is an integer positive variable, even (i don't think such detail is particularly useful).

I tried, factor, collect, simplify etc...

Comment: Is it $82$ or $8 \cdot 2$?

Comment: It is $8 \times 2$

Comment: Too short for a comment.

$8=2^3$

Comment: Is the question how do you reduce by hand or is it how do you use maple to reduce?

Comment: How to use maple to reduce the expression, specifically i just to want to pass from the original expression to the (1), assuming is possible. I would also like to be able to pass from the original one to the (2), otherwise I want just to know how to reduce it as much as i can.

Comment: I think you need to be more explicit in the post since using "I am newbie in maple" does not immediately lead to asking for help with maple. IMHO

Comment: The question is simple... IMHO... do you know which sequence of maple statements could let me transform my original expression into (1)? I was thinking something like a sequence of simplify, factor etc... I tried but i don't reach the expression I'm looking for. So i don't get if maple is "smart enough" to provide me the (1). The "newbie" means "maybe there's some special command that I don't know or i can't come up which sequence of maple statements could help me".

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:**

Use the following factorization:
$$8=2^3$$

Comment: I tried these two statements:
>h = -8*2^q+1+8*2^((3/2)*q) then
>factor(h, 2^3)
it returns an error, saying that "8" is not a valid algebraic expression

Comment: Do you mind showing me the sequence of statements you used?

Answer (score 0):

Maple has trouble recognizing a number as anything but exactly that: $2^3$ is just the number $8$ to Maple, not the other way around. You can work around this, however, with the following substitutions,

```
g:=q->-8*2^(q)+8*2^(3/2*q)+1;

subs(8=2^x, -8=-2^x, g(q));
simplify(%);
subs(x = 3, %);
```

This gives you (1), however this is one of those cases where the computer program does not recognize things as well as you do. I think you need to motivate why you wish to get something like (2) - if you are looking to check your own solution for root finding, you could use the `is` command

```
is(g(q) = 2^(q+3)*(2^(q/2)-1)+1); # is g(q) equal to (2)
```

otherwise, for root finding, `solve` should work just fine.

Comment: I'll give it a try and I let you know.